# How to free space for dropped database in MemSql

Tags: scala, singlestore

I am new to MemSQL. I have created a database and tables in MemSQL on cluster with 5 leaf nodes and 2 aggregator nodes. Spark is running on the same cluster.
Everything is in default mode. Inserted data and deleted the same. select * does not return anything. But when I saw web clusterUI, each leaf nodes are still consuming around 6TB of disk space.

[image]
[image]
**Disk Capacity** description says "This is is amount of disk space used by MemSQL relative to total disk space available. When this is full, no snapshot, transaction logs or columnstore data can be created".

With this description, I assume that above 6TB disk space is because of MemSQL usage.

Can some please clarify

1. Does by default MemSQL write data to disk too ?
2. Does is not delete the data written on disk even after deleting content and dropping table?
3. How can I free disk space consumed by MemSQL? Which directory I hvae to delete?  I figured out that directory "/var/lib/memsql/leaf-3306" has all memsql artifacts for this leaf node.

Comment: you forgot to bleep out the URL in the second screenshot :)

Comment: here I scratched URL. :)

Comment: Though I have dropped database, show databases shows below databases information_schema, memsql, sharding. I have not created them. No one has access to this cluster. Should I drop them too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 6TB usage might be because of MemSQL, or it might be because of Spark or some other process.  MemSQL ops reports total disk usage, not disk used by MemSQL (the tooltip is slightly misleading).

1) Rowstore tables (tables WITHOUT a CLUSTERD COLUMNSTORE index) write logs to disk for every write.  The logs are combined into snapshots when the logs become to large, and by default, we keep the last two snapshot files.  Thus, it is possible that the older of the two snapshots contains the data you deleted.  You can trigger a new snapshot with `SNAPSHOT <dbName>`, and this will let GC cleanup the old (possibly large) ones.

2) Snapshots and logs are per database, not per table.  Dropping a table will not trigger snapshot/log cleanup, but dropping the database or triggering a new snapshot will.

3) You probably shouldn't delete data directories by hand.  `DROP DATABASE <db_name>` will delete all data associated with that database.

For columnstore tables, the story is slightly different, but I assume "Everything is default" means no columnstore tables.

Comment: "MemSQL ops reports total disk usage, not disk used by MemSQL" then I am kind of relieved. Let me check if disk space is used someone else

Comment: After getting clarification on misleading description on Disk Capacity, I deleted other files on my disk and it cleared disk space.

Answer (score 2):

Did you drop a database (as in, `DROP DATABASE db`) or delete all the data (as in `DELETE FROM t` or `TRUNCATE TABLE t`)?

If former, disk usage should have shrank immediately, and if it has not, I can help you investigate what's consuming it.

If latter, then it makes perfect sense. MemSQL is using transactional logs and snapshots for durability. In this particular case, when you insert `X` amount of data, and then delete `X` amount of data, the transactional log will be `2X` long on the disk, so that on recovery it can replay all the inserts and all the deletes. To shrink it, MemSQL occasionally takes snapshots (some other database engines call them checkpoints). It usually does so when the logs reach certain size, which in your case, apparently, was not reached yet. If you want to free up the disk space, you can manually trigger a snapshot, run `SNAPSHOT db` on the aggregator (`db` is the name of your database), and it should help.

Comment: I have dropped database but it didn't reduce disk space. "show databases" shows below databases 'information_schema', 'memsql', 'sharding'. I have not created them. No one has access to this cluster. Should I drop them too?

Comment: Most certainly do not drop those databases. They are memsql's system databases and are required for memsql to operate properly (most likely you will not be able to drop them anyway)

Answer (score -2):

The memory occupied will not be free until GC is triggered. Memsql keeps all data in memory. Even if we delete tables, database,rows,etc  memory will not be available if GC is not happening.
Enforce GC from command prompt , it will release memory :

**memsql>  trigger full gc flush;**

compare **free -m** before and after triggering the command.
You will see the difference  :)

Comment: MemSQL will run its GC automatically, there isn't any need to run trigger gc.  The flush option in particular will cause memsql to free up cached memory (Buffer_manager_cached_memory) which will adversely impact query performance (and MemSQL will just recache the memory later anyways).

For more details on digging into what is using memory see:
https://help.memsql.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001091386-What-Is-Using-Memory-on-My-Leaves-